# CS1963 An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

form method="POST" asp-controller="Person" asp-action="Save">

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Firstname">Lastname:</label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Firstname" value="@Model.Firstname" />
</div>
```

and the tag helpers are in the _viewimport file @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

i have an error when i try to use the input taghelper, asp-action, asp-controller working.i get this error; An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation.